# Can I use @Autowired in custom filter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using @Autowire in  custom filter class. I'm getting  null pointer exception.

Does @Autowire works in Filter?

here is the code:

```
public class MyFilter extends CustomFilter {

@Autowire
public MyClass myClass;

@Override
public String getInfo(){
return myClass.getMessage();
}
}
```

This is how I registered my bean in  configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigLoader{ 

@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean myFilterBean() {
      final FilterRegistrationBean filterBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
      filterBean.setFilter(new MyFilter());
      filterBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
      return filterBean;
    }
}
```

Custom filter:

```
public abstract class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
        return this.filterConfig;
    }

    public void setFilterConfig(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        this.clearContext();
    }

    protected abstract String getInfo();
}
```

Comment: The Autowired annotation does nothing if the filter is not registered as a component.

Comment: It depends on how is CustomFilter defined

Comment: you mean If I add @Component on MyFilter class does it work?

Comment: Please write a code that compiles :  `@Autowired`, `extends`,

Comment: And please detail the `CustomFilter` class hierarchy.

Comment: added code for custom filter

Comment: @Compass, I added component annotation on MyFilter class , still I see null pointer exception.

Comment: Add an `@Bean`annotated method creating and returning a new MyFilter. Call this method from your myFilterBean() method. That's how the filter will become a component.

Answer (score 8):

Add `@Component` annotation to filter class.

```
@Component
public class MyFilter extends CustomFilter {

...
```

Let Spring create the filter bean and autowire it in the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigLoader{ 

@Autowired
private MyFilter myFilter;

@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean myFilterBean() {
      final FilterRegistrationBean filterBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
      filterBean.setFilter(myFilter);
      filterBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
      return filterBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to @autowire MyClass in filter not for the MyFilter class

Comment: Yes. That's why you have to annotate Myfilter with `@Component`. And that's why you have to `@Autowired` it into the configuration instead of creating it manually.

Comment: @component marking make the filter automatically added as last filter. You dont need filter registration bean

Comment: This solution works. Be careful, not to set the same name for the bean and class, because Spring will complain that the object name already exists.